# How to pivot Rows as columns, and show by the last 7 days - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, data-manipulation

Im trying to get the times of employees for the last 7 days (not including today)

I have a table of result that looks like this

```
|EmpID | Date       | Totaltime|
|------|------------|----------|
|1001  | 2020-12-17 |   1000   | 
|1001  | 2020-12-16 |   2641   |
|1001  | 2020-12-14 |   1532   |
```

I need to pivot the date rows as columns going backwards from day 1 (yesterday) to day 7 (8 days ago)

The result should look like this:

```
|EmpID | Day1 | Day2 | Day3 | Day4 | Day5 | Day6 | Day7 |
|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|------|
|1001  | 1000 | 2641 |      | 1532 |      |      |      |
```

As you can see Day3, Day5, Day6, Day7 are empty because they had no values.

I can't seem to find a quick way of achieving this. The PIVOT functionality requires you to hard code the dates which is not suitable as I wouldn't always know the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use date arithmetics and conditional aggregation like so:

```
select empid,
    max(case when date = dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, getdate())) then totaltime end) as day1,
    max(case when date = dateadd(day, -2, convert(date, getdate())) then totaltime end) as day2,
    ...
from mytable
group by empid
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, this is a dynamic pivot which always uses last 7 days. If you want the output as Day1, Day2, Day3 etc. and don't know how to do that by yourself I can edit the query. Also, as you can see in the output this reurns the sum od Totaltime, if you don't want a sum than just change it to MAX.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tbl;
CREATE TABLE #tbl(EmpId int, [Date] date, Totaltime int);

INSERT INTO #tbl(EmpId, [Date], Totaltime)
VALUES (1001 , '2020-12-17' ,  1000)
,(1001 , '2020-12-16' ,  241) 
,(1001 , '2020-12-14' ,  1532)
,(1002 , '2020-12-17' ,  100)
,(1002 , '2020-12-16' ,  23641) 
,(1003 , '2020-12-14' ,  153)
,(1003 , '2020-12-11' ,  200)
,(1003 , '2020-12-11' ,  300);



DECLARE @sql  nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @columnname nvarchar(max);


;with cte as
(SELECT dateadd(day,-1,CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) AS dt
UNION ALL
SELECT dateadd(day,-1,cte.dt)
FROM cte
WHERE cte.dt>dateadd(day,-7,CAST(GETDATE() AS date))
)
SELECT @columnname=COALESCE(@columnname+ ',', '') + QUOTENAME(CAST(cte.dt AS nvarchar(20)),'[]')
FROM cte;

/*USE MAX INSTEAD OF SUM BELOW IF YOU JUST WANT VALUES AND NOT A SUM*/
SET @sql='
SELECT *
FROM #tbl t
PIVOT
(SUM(TotalTime)
FOR [Date] IN('+@columnname+')) AS p'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Similar to another answer, this is a dynamic script that will always grab the prior 7 days and pivot by them. It builds a temp table with the relevant dates, string_agg's them into a single record and then passes it to the dynamic pivot.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tbl;
CREATE TABLE #tbl(EmpId int, [Date] date, Totaltime int);

INSERT INTO #tbl(EmpId, [Date], Totaltime)
VALUES (1001 , '2020-12-17' ,  1000)
,(1001 , '2020-12-16' ,  241) 
,(1001 , '2020-12-14' ,  1532)
,(1002 , '2020-12-17' ,  100)
,(1002 , '2020-12-16' ,  23641) 
,(1003 , '2020-12-14' ,  153)
,(1003 , '2020-12-11' ,  200)
,(1003 , '2020-12-11' ,  300);

DECLARE @Date DATE
SET @Date = DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Date
CREATE TABLE #Date (Date DATE)

WHILE @Date <= DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE())
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Date VALUES (@Date)
    SET @Date = DATEADD(DAY,1,@Date)
END

DECLARE @PivotDate VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
@PivotDate = STRING_AGG(CONCAT('[',Date,']'),',') 
FROM #Date

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQL = 
'
SELECT
*
FROM #tbl
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Totaltime)
    FOR Date IN (' + @PivotDate + ')
) p'

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```